# How to use setInterval in create timer

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a timer in page like this.

```html
<h5 class="pa-2 text-center">{{ timestamp }}</h5>
```

initial `timestamp: '',` in data and i have a function for set timestamp.

**function in methods**

```js
getNow() {
  const today = new Date();
  const date1 = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
  const time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  const dateTime = date1 + "    " + time;
  this.timestamp = dateTime;
}
```

and use this function in mounted.

```js
setInterval(() => this.getNow() , 1000);
```

i have 2 error in every second .
error :
*[Vue warn]: Property or method "date" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.*

Comment: post the code for whole component!, you are probably using the variable "date" somewhere in the code, that's causing the error.

Comment: Post your whole code. The method/property called "date" doesn't appear in the current code.